# Spring Boot - Generic prototype bean autowiring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, generics, spring-boot

We have a legacy project in which there are classes called `DataProcessor`. So each module of project has their own data processor and they all extend one class called `BasicDataProcessor`. For e.g.

```
public ProductDataProcessor extends BasicDataProcessor {
      public ProductDataProcessor(String logFileDirectory, String loggingLevel){
           /*constructor code*/
      }
}

public CustomerDataProcessor extends BasicDataProcessor {
      public CustomerDataProcessor(String logFileDirectory, String loggingLevel){
           /*constructor code*/
      }
}
```

There are lot of such `Data Processor` and they all have their own constructor which initialize the particular data processor with passed properties as constructor parameter.

We are converting this legacy application into Spring Boot app. And my goal is to autowire this data processor (which includes most of business logic)  in respective @Service class of Spring. So for e.g. `ProductService` will have `ProductDataProcessor` autowired.

```
public class ProductService {

     @Autowired
     private ProductDataProcessor productDataProcessor;

     /*-----------------------
       --Other service code---
       -----------------------*/
}
```

One way is to create @Configuration class and initialize each such data processors with their properties. I can specify data processor specific properties in property file and read from there also.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value =  ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public ProductDataProcessor productDataProcessor(String logFileDirectory, String loggingLevel){
        return new ProductDataProcessor(logFileDirectory, loggingLevel);    
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------
      --------------------------------------------
      --------------------------------------------
      ---------other Data Processor Beans---------
      --------------------------------------------
      --------------------------------------------*/
}
```

And then `ProductService` will have the `productDataProcessor` autowired.

Is there any other elegant and generic way to achieve that? For instance, a generic prototype bean which will create a new instance based on what type of `Data Processor` object been asked for.

```
@Bean
    @Scope(value =  ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public BasicDataProcessor productDataProcessor(String logFileDirectory, String loggingLevel, String dataProcessorClassType){
        // create an object of `dataProcessorClassType` and return
    }
```

Or any other work around considering the each data processor class is extending `BasicDataProcessor`?

Comment: couple of questions 1. Can you tweak this legacy classes(Processor classes) 2. The busines logic u mentioned is not in constructor right?I guess in some other function which is overrided from base class

Comment: No...that is not advisable as there is a lot of business logic in it and if we do it, there are chances that code may break at some point. So I want to avoid it as much as possible. And no business logic in controller. Basically we will be having all controllers as `RestController`. We converting this application into API project. So `RestControllers` are just one layer of API above it.

Comment: I asked contrcutor not controller

Comment: Ohhh...My Bad....No business logic in constructor...all the business logic is in several methods of  each`DataProcessor` class.